# Why are all of Mr. Shirley's gifts the same?

Tags: plot-explanation, props, christmas-vacation

In [*Christmas Vacation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Lampoon%27s_Christmas_Vacation),  Clark is bringing his boss, Mr. Shirley a Christmas gift.  Mr. Shirley is annoyed at being interrupted and tells Clark to put it with the others.

The other gifts are on a table behind Clark.  All of the gifts are the same exact size and shape as is the one that Clark has.

[image: gifts]

**Is there any reason why the gifts are the same?   Is this ever explained?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It draws attention to Mr. Shirley's value of each of his employee's offerings.

By making it appear to be the same in shape, and by placing it among several that have been placed before him, we see that several of his employees have had the same idea: offer a seemingly gracious gift in hopes of working him over to return a bonus in exchange.

As Mr. Shirley advises to put it with the other ones, we understand that Clark's offer is held in the same esteem as everyone that has come before him.  The Jelly of the Month Club bonus solidifies Shirley's sentiment.

Comment: But...the jelly of the month club is the gift that keeps giving the whole year! :P

Comment: Token gifts most likely.  Today's equivalent would be a Starbucks gift card.