# What gift does Clarke give his boss, Mr. Shirley in Nation Lampoons Christmas Vacation?

Tags: christmas-vacation

In the movie, Clarke gives a gift to his boss and all of the boxes are the exact same shape. Is it everyone hinted/explained what the gift was? And why they were all the same?

Answer (score 2):

According to IMDB trivia, the gift was a desk organizer. To explain why, see [this question and answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84090/why-are-all-of-mr-shirleys-gifts-the-same) However, a desk organizer is still speculation as it isn't revealed in the movie. It may be somewhere in the script, though.

> All the presents that were on the credenza when Clark went in to give
>   his to Mr. Shirley are identically shaped, and likely the same gift.
>   It is a desk organizer. When this movie came out, pen sets came in an
>   L-shaped arrangement. The writing instruments were on the flat part,
>   and the raised section held Post-It notes. Paper clips and other
>   holders were also a possibility.

[Source](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097958/trivia?item=tr1033690)